# querySelector/getElementByClassName order in nested items

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, selectors-api

I need to understand how this works so I can code the right stuff.

```
<div class="element">
  <div class="content">
    <contents>
    <div class="element">
      <contents>
      <div class="thisClass"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thisClass"></div>
</div>
```

I have the element that includes a child element with similar structure and classes. If I do

```
var element = document.querySelector('.element'); // this returns the parent
element.querySelector('.thisClass') // ok I got it so far
```

EDIT:
I want to make sure to always get the element ('.thisClass') from the parent, no matter what is the order of the parent's child elements, and using the best possible script.

I am very tired working like a workaholic, I'm a newbie with native JS, I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Try it and use console.log to show which

Comment: MDN - `querySelector()` - ["Returns the first element within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: If you need to just mess around with simple code like this, you should check out https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `document.querySelector('.element') === document.querySelectorAll('.element')[0] === document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0]`

Comment: @ShadowCat7 Not even necessary. SO has code editor too

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, but it would be better to find the answer yourself by using jsfiddle than come here and use the code editor.

Comment: What I meant was while writing the question, the answer would already appear

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> var element = document.querySelector('.element'); // this returns the parent
> element.querySelector('.thisClass')
> ```
>
> what would this return and why?

It would return this element:

```
<div class="element">
  <div class="content">
    <contents>
    <div class="element">
      <contents>
      <div class="thisClass"></div><!-- <===== Here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thisClass"></div>
</div>
```

The "why" is because `querySelector` and methods like it work in *document order*, which is the order of the document from top to bottom (e.g., as though written out as HTML). Or to put it another way, it's a [*depth-first* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) of the element.

---

Re your edit:

> I want to make sure to always get the element ('.thisClass') from the parent, no matter what is the order of the parent's child elements, and using the best possible script.

That **completely changes** the question. And the answer is: You can't use `querySelector` for that (well, not without fudging things a bit). You have two options:

1. Loop through the parent element's `childNodes` (or `children`) list, or
2. Fudge things a bit and use `querySelector`

#1 is fairly obvious, but for completeness:

```
var element = document.querySelector('.element');
var targetElement, node;
for (node = element.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.className.match(/\bthisClass\b/)) {
        targetElement = node;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or if you can rely on using a modern-ish browser, you can use `firstElementChild` and `nextElementSibling` and skip the `nodeType` check.

#2 is more work for the browser and probably hard to justify in this case where you're just looking for something simple like a class name, but here's what fudging `querySelector` looks like:

```
var markerId = "some-unique-string-you-know-is-not-used-as-an-id-in-your-document";
var element = document.querySelector('.element');
if (!element.id) {
    element.id = markerId;
}
var targetElement = document.querySelector('#' + markerId + ' > .thisClass');
if (element.id == markerId) {
    element.id = "";
}
```

You can see how that works: We make sure the element has an `id`, then use a *direct child combinator* with `document.querySelector` (not `element.querySelector`) looking for the first immediate child of the element with that `id`. Then we remove the `id` if we set it.

Again, it's more work for the browser, and the code's not shorter, but there might be use cases if you have complex selectors...

Comment: I guess folks are peeved that OP did not even try to figure it out and hence should not get any answers

Comment: I was just working on an answer too, but dem downvotes... I guess I shan't waste my time.

Comment: The OP's question oozes pure lazy, but T.J. Crowder is spot on. I'm betting the OP is confused as to why the 2nd call wouldn't be the same as the first, which is readily explained by the presence of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Comment: @mplungjan: Looks like. The thing is, experimenting will give you the *what* but not the *why*. So I figured, give them the why. :-)

Comment: Reading the easily available documentation of querySelector does however give that info

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder it's exactly what I needed to know: WHY. Very bad of those who voted down. I will delete this to prevent further "being a troll".

Comment: @mplungjan: 'tis true.

Comment: I forgot to mention, my question is here because I know querySelector is not fully implemented in IE8, so I also want to know if IE8 would do same thing as you answered.

Comment: @thednp: querySelector is fully implemented in IE8.

Comment: @BoltClock you are perfectly right, I found out about it too, thanks  http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited the question, now you should surely understand why I ask.

Comment: @thednp: I understood the original question. :-) But the edit *changes* the question, substantially; I suggest asking a new question about it.

Comment: @thednp: ***But*** I went ahead and updated the answer. In future, though, best not to completely change the question after you've received answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to visualize it:

```
(function () {
  'use strict'

  var element1 = document.querySelector('.element')
  var element2 = document.querySelector('.thisClass')

  /* .element will have a red border */
  /* .thisClass will have a yellow border */

  element1.style.border = '5px solid red'
  element2.style.border = '5px solid yellow'
})()
```

I created a demo on jsBin to try that out: [demo](http://jsbin.com/juzecuvayo/3/edit?html,js,output)

As you can see, `document.querySelector` always returns the first element in document order.

Comment: Thanks! I remember how I struggled with JS when I started it, so I'm glad to help ;)